# webapp2 decorator routes with Google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I would like to define routes on my RequestHandler objects by decorating them rather than providing the application with a list when it is created.

My WSGIApplication is defined as follows:

```
class WSGIApplication(webapp2.WSGIApplication):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WSGIApplication, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.router.set_dispatcher(self.__class__.custom_dispatcher)

    @staticmethod
    def custom_dispatcher(router, request, response):
        rv = router.default_dispatcher(request, response)
        if isinstance(rv, basestring):
            rv = webapp2.Response(rv)
        elif isinstance(rv, tuple):
            rv = webapp2.Response(*rv)

        return rv

    def route(self, url, name):
        def outer_wrapped(cls):
            logging.info("Adding route %s to class %s with name %s"
                         % (url, cls, name))
            self.router.add(RedirectRoute(url, cls,
                                          name=name,
                                          strict_slash=True))
            return cls
        return outer_wrapped
```

in `package.utils`

And I have my application defined in `package.application`

app.yaml has

```
application: theapplication
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: package.main.application
  secure: always
```

`package.main` is as follows:

```
from package.application import application
from package.pages import pages
```

`package.application` is as follows (with the secret key hashed out):

```
from package import utils

conf = {}
conf['webapp2_extras.sessions'] = {'secret_key':
    """##############################################"""}

application = utils.WSGIApplication([], config=conf)
```

and here are a couple of handlers from `package.pages`:

```
from package.application import application as app


@app.route('/conversations', 'view_messages')
class Messages(BaseHandler):
    @users.require_login
    def get(self):
        conversations = self.current_user.get_user_conversations()
        return self.render('conversations.slim', conversations=conversations)


@app.route('/', 'index')
class Index(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        return self.render('index.slim')
```

The index page works fine, everything else 404s, the log simply says:

```
INFO     2012-07-23 14:23:46,258 __init__.py:26] /notifications
INFO     2012-07-23 14:23:46,272 dev_appserver.py:2952] "GET /notifications HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

<del>I presume this is caused in some way by appengine's import caching preventing the decorators from ever being run and adding themselves to the app.</del>

Of course I fell prey to the trap of assuming I had any clue of what was causing the problem. I added further logging statements to output the list of routes before attempting each dispatch and I find that all of the routes are in the router as one would expect:

```
    ...
    def custom_dispatcher(router, request, response):
        logging.info(router.match_routes)
        logging.info(router.build_routes)
        rv = router.default_dispatcher(request, response)
    ...
```

With the following log output on pointing my browser to /conversations:

```
INFO     2012-08-04 13:16:40,513 utils.py:13] [<Route('/friendship', <class 'package.pages.pages.Friendship'>, name='friendship', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/friendship/', <class 'webapp2.RedirectHandler'>, name=None, defaults={'_uri': <bound method RedirectRoute._redirect of <Route('/friendship', <class 'package.pages.pages.Friendship'>, name='friendship', defaults={}, build_only=False)>>, '_name': 'friendship'}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/signup', <class 'package.pages.pages.Signup'>, name='signup', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/signup/', <class 'webapp2.RedirectHandler'>, name=None, defaults={'_uri': <bound method RedirectRoute._redirect of <Route('/signup', <class 'package.pages.pages.Signup'>, name='signup', defaults={}, build_only=False)>>, '_name': 'signup'}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/preferences', <class 'package.pages.pages.UserPage'>, name='user_prefs', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/preferences/', <class 'webapp2.RedirectHandler'>, name=None, defaults={'_uri': <bound method RedirectRoute._redirect of <Route('/preferences', <class 'package.pages.pages.UserPage'>, name='user_prefs', defaults={}, build_only=False)>>, '_name': 'user_prefs'}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/<username:[a-zA-Z]+>', <class 'package.pages.pages.UserPage'>, name='user_page', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/<username:[a-zA-Z]+>/', <class 'webapp2.RedirectHandler'>, name=None, defaults={'_uri': <bound method RedirectRoute._redirect of <Route('/<username:[a-zA-Z]+>', <class 'package.pages.pages.UserPage'>, name='user_page', defaults={}, build_only=False)>>, '_name': 'user_page'}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/message', <class 'package.pages.pages.SendMessagePage'>, name='send_message', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/message/', <class 'webapp2.RedirectHandler'>, name=None, defaults={'_uri': <bound method RedirectRoute._redirect of <Route('/message', <class 'package.pages.pages.SendMessagePage'>, name='send_message', defaults={}, build_only=False)>>, '_name': 'send_message'}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/conversations', <class 'package.pages.pages.Messages'>, name='view_messages', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/conversations/', <class 'webapp2.RedirectHandler'>, name=None, defaults={'_uri': <bound method RedirectRoute._redirect of <Route('/conversations', <class 'package.pages.pages.Messages'>, name='view_messages', defaults={}, build_only=False)>>, '_name': 'view_messages'}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/conversation/<conversation_id>', <class 'package.pages.pages.ConversationPage'>, name='conversation', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/conversation/<conversation_id>/', <class 'webapp2.RedirectHandler'>, name=None, defaults={'_uri': <bound method RedirectRoute._redirect of <Route('/conversation/<conversation_id>', <class 'package.pages.pages.ConversationPage'>, name='conversation', defaults={}, build_only=False)>>, '_name': 'conversation'}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/boards', <class 'package.pages.pages.Boards'>, name='view_boards', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/boards/', <class 'webapp2.RedirectHandler'>, name=None, defaults={'_uri': <bound method RedirectRoute._redirect of <Route('/boards', <class 'package.pages.pages.Boards'>, name='view_boards', defaults={}, build_only=False)>>, '_name': 'view_boards'}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/boards/<board>', <class 'package.pages.pages.BoardPage'>, name='view_board', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/boards/<board>/', <class 'webapp2.RedirectHandler'>, name=None, defaults={'_uri': <bound method RedirectRoute._redirect of <Route('/boards/<board>', <class 'package.pages.pages.BoardPage'>, name='view_board', defaults={}, build_only=False)>>, '_name': 'view_board'}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/boards/<board>/new_thread', <class 'package.pages.pages.NewThreadPage'>, name='new_thread', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/boards/<board>/new_thread/', <class 'webapp2.RedirectHandler'>, name=None, defaults={'_uri': <bound method RedirectRoute._redirect of <Route('/boards/<board>/new_thread', <class 'package.pages.pages.NewThreadPage'>, name='new_thread', defaults={}, build_only=False)>>, '_name': 'new_thread'}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/notifications', <class 'package.pages.pages.Notifications'>, name='notifications', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/notifications/', <class 'webapp2.RedirectHandler'>, name=None, defaults={'_uri': <bound method RedirectRoute._redirect of <Route('/notifications', <class 'package.pages.pages.Notifications'>, name='notifications', defaults={}, build_only=False)>>, '_name': 'notifications'}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/img/<blob_key>', <class 'package.pages.pages.DisplayImagePage'>, name='display_image', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/img/<blob_key>/', <class 'webapp2.RedirectHandler'>, name=None, defaults={'_uri': <bound method RedirectRoute._redirect of <Route('/img/<blob_key>', <class 'package.pages.pages.DisplayImagePage'>, name='display_image', defaults={}, build_only=False)>>, '_name': 'display_image'}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/', <class 'package.pages.pages.Index'>, name='index', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, <Route('/', <class 'webapp2.RedirectHandler'>, name=None, defaults={'_uri': <bound method RedirectRoute._redirect of <Route('/', <class 'package.pages.pages.Index'>, name='index', defaults={}, build_only=False)>>, '_name': 'index'}, build_only=False)>]
INFO     2012-08-04 13:16:40,513 utils.py:14] {'index': <Route('/', <class 'package.pages.pages.Index'>, name='index', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, 'view_boards': <Route('/boards', <class 'package.pages.pages.Boards'>, name='view_boards', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, 'notifications': <Route('/notifications', <class 'package.pages.pages.Notifications'>, name='notifications', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, 'friendship': <Route('/friendship', <class 'package.pages.pages.Friendship'>, name='friendship', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, 'signup': <Route('/signup', <class 'package.pages.pages.Signup'>, name='signup', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, 'view_messages': <Route('/conversations', <class 'package.pages.pages.Messages'>, name='view_messages', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, 'conversation': <Route('/conversation/<conversation_id>', <class 'package.pages.pages.ConversationPage'>, name='conversation', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, 'send_message': <Route('/message', <class 'package.pages.pages.SendMessagePage'>, name='send_message', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, 'new_thread': <Route('/boards/<board>/new_thread', <class 'package.pages.pages.NewThreadPage'>, name='new_thread', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, 'view_board': <Route('/boards/<board>', <class 'package.pages.pages.BoardPage'>, name='view_board', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, 'display_image': <Route('/img/<blob_key>', <class 'package.pages.pages.DisplayImagePage'>, name='display_image', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, 'user_prefs': <Route('/preferences', <class 'package.pages.pages.UserPage'>, name='user_prefs', defaults={}, build_only=False)>, 'user_page': <Route('/<username:[a-zA-Z]+>', <class 'package.pages.pages.UserPage'>, name='user_page', defaults={}, build_only=False)>}
INFO     2012-08-04 13:16:40,515 __init__.py:26] /conversations
INFO     2012-08-04 13:16:40,533 dev_appserver.py:2952] "GET /conversations HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2012-08-04 13:16:40,626 dev_appserver.py:2952] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

What on earth am I failing to notice?

Comment: I've updated the post as requested. I was under the impression that adding a main function is only for older non-threadsafe runtimes using cgi.

Comment: You were right. I tried it and it works both ways. I think the problem is that your decorators should read application.route instead of app.route (app is not defined anywhere or is it in packages.pages?), but that should raise an error.

Comment: Oh I'm doing `from package.application import application as app`

Comment: What have you tried when it comes to debugging? Is your handler updating the routes list as you expect it to? What do you see if you log the router's list of routes at the end of your main module? Also, why are you defining a custom dispatcher?

Comment: The custom dispatcher is so that I can return a string instead of writing to a response

Comment: Where do you define a mapping for '/notifications'? I can only see the mapping for '/conversations' in your question.

Comment: Sorry the code I've given is an excerpt; I get an identical error for conversations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a route that was overriding all the other routes but raising a 404 on them (/username leads to a user page; there's no user called "conversations"). I had forgotten to make this route have lowest priority in the switch to the decorator routing method.

I figured this out by first building a minimal application using the same routing method to see that it worked just fine on app engine. Then I caught HTTPNotFound exceptions in my handler and printed a stack trace when they occurred; this made it pretty clear that it was a line in the get method of my user page class throwing a 404 intentionally then the problems was fairly obvious.